# Opening a file from Nemo does not set current working directory

Tags: nemo, cwd

Suppose I have a file `~/work/report.txt`.

If I open a terminal and change directory to `~/work/`, then issue

```
gvim report.txt
```

I get a gvim window where `report.txt` is opened and

```
:pwd
```

gives back `~/work/`. This is the behavior I want.

In contrast, if I open the file browser and navigate to `~/work`, then double click on `report.txt`, I get a gvim window that opens `report.txt` but for which :pwd gives back ~.

How can I make the double-click behavior the same as the command line behavior?

This is on Linux Mint 18 (Sarah) Cinnamon. The file browser in question is the default, Nemo.

Comment: gives me absolute path (~ is not used) in either case for me on ubuntu 16.04, not sure if it is something to do with what I've installed (version 7.4, Included patches: 1-1689) or some setting in my vimrc.. also, path of the file is usually shown on the title bar of gvim

Comment: Can you explain why this is a problem in your question? Doing `chdir` on execute/open is rather a Windows-like behavior, I would say.